# It is possible to have implicit kind in a Fortran procedure

Tags: fortran, deferred

Taking a procedure such as

```
function c(a,b)
  integer,parameter        :: dp=kind(2.0e0) 
  real(kind=dp),intent(in) :: a,b
  real(kind=dp)            :: c
  c=a+b
end function
```

Is there a way to call the same function in the same program with different kinds? For example:

```
program help
  integer,parameter    :: sp=kind(2.0d0),dp=kind(2.0e0) 
  print *, c(2.0_dp,3.0_dp)
  print *, c(2.0_sp,3.0_sp)
end program
```

I know that I can write again the function `c` using `sp` parameters and give an interface that hide the two in one, but I'm looking for a solution that don't need to create another function... may be just modify the existing one?

Comment: Your kinds are mixed up.

Comment: Why is this tagged "Deferred"? Am I missing something?

Comment: There are mixed because that was my question. I forget the "??" symbols so I edit to add them and correct the sentence: **Is there a way to call the same funcion in the same program with diferents kinds??. For example:**

Comment: With "Deferred" I refer to the mechanism that a process can to know implicitly the size of an array:
`subroutine pp(a);
 real(a) :: a(:);
print *,  size(a);
end`.
I extract the word from Fortran 2003 standar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to write a function that accepts arguments of the different kinds of real (or any of the other intrinsics).  As you already know, the standard way to write code which is kind-indifferent is to write implementations for each of the kinds you are concerned with and to wrap them in an interface.

You could, if you prefer something more kludgy, write a routine for low-precision kinds which wraps a call to the matching routine for high-precision kinds and incorporates some kind adjustment.  Personally I prefer the interface route to this.

Finally, you may well find that your compiler allows you to get away with passing arguments of the wrong kind to a routine, performing some automatic kind adjustment behind the scenes.  This is non-standard and likely to be non-portable.